# How to speed up transition for bootstrap nav-collapse

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

Hi I have the following html code for bootstrap `nav-collapse`, Sometimes when I click on the menu it's takes time to open and when I click on the menu name it also takes time to close and sometimes it will stuck  and close by itself. Is it a bug or something else? I have applied transition to it.
I need it to be smooth when the click the menu, it should open smoothly and close smoothly. Is there anything i am missing in it?

I am using Internet Explorer as my browser

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a rel="nofollow" class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" title="Toggle menu">
        <span class="menu-name">Menu</span>
        <span class="menu-bars">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
        <ul class="nav" id="topMenu" data-submenu="horizontal">
          <li class=" active " style="">
            <a rel="nofollow" href="//ss-template-blog03.simplesite.com/434337774">FRONT PAGE</a>
          </li>
          <li class="  " style="">
            <a rel="nofollow" href="//ss-template-blog03.simplesite.com/434337775">BLOG</a>
          </li>
          <li class="  " style="">
            <a rel="nofollow" href="//ss-template-blog03.simplesite.com/434337777">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.collapse {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height .100s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .35s ease;
  -o-transition: height .35s ease;
  transition: height .35s ease;
}
```

My image of the menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code for your `nav-collapse`.

> For more help on bootstrap `nav-collapse` read this [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Even i use the website bootstrap. It still causing some problems like. when i click the hamburger it's very slow to dropdown the items

Comment: could you make a working snippet of your code, without this it will be tough to find your issue.